# Finding maximum no of $1$'s

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, combinations

We are given a matrix $A \in M_n (F)$ such that all its entires are either $1$ or $0$. I need to find the maximum number of $1$'s that can be in matrix $A$ so that it is still invertible.

My try : for matrix $A$ to be invertible it must have atleast $n$ $1$'s.Now I could reach only upto a triangular matrix with all its entires including diagonal entries being $1$ and thus total count being $$\frac{n^2+n}{2}$$ 
I think there are even more matrices.

How can we find the answer ?

Comment: What if only the entries on the diagonal are zero?

Comment: The matrix wont be invertible right ?

Comment: Isn't $\pmatrix{0&1\cr1&0\cr}$ invertible? and $\pmatrix{0&1&1\cr1&0&1\cr1&1&0\cr}$ also?

Comment: Oh ! yeah . didn’t realize. Sorry. But then How to prove it rigorously ?

Answer (score 3):

In fact, all the diagonal entries need not be zero. There can be one non-zero entry on the diagonal and the matrix will still be invertible. That is, if $A(i,j) =1, \forall i\ne j$ and $A(1,1) = 1$, $A(i,i) = 0, \forall i\ne 1$, we will have $A$ invertible.

So, that gives a lower bound on #1's: $n^2-n+1$.

To prove that $A$ is invertible: Consider writing $A$ as

$$A = B - I,$$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $B$ is a matrix with $B(i,j) = 2$ for $i=j=1$ and $B(i,j) = 1$ otherwise. So, clearly $$det(A) =0 $$ implies $\lambda = 1$ is an eigen value of $B$. Let us see if $1$ is an eigen value of $B$. Let us assume so to start with - implies there exists a  non zero vector $v\in {\mathbb R}^n$  such that 
$$Bv = v,$$ i.e., $$\sum_{k=1}^n v_k = v_i, \forall i\ne1$$ and $$2v_1+\sum_{k=2}^n v_k = v_1.$$ Solving these, we get $v=0$, clearly a contradiction. So, $A$ is invertible.

Comment: And that's the maximum. With more ones than that, at least two rows will have all ones.

Comment: That was cool -- I did not bother to look at it all...

Comment: Well, Shash, you have to *prove* that that matrix is invertible. Presumably, you can subtract one row from all the others to get a matrix that's mostly zeros, and then you can calculate the determinant, maybe using induction.

Comment: Edited my answer to include the proof.